# Extract a line from a file using cut without without including other lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a command that extracts a line from a file. The line I am trying to extract is a delimited line and I am selecting the second field.

This is the command I could come up with: `cut -d':' -f2 file.txt`.

This is the file for context:

```
Hello world

Name:Age:DOB:Gender
```

In this case, I am trying to extract the second field and display it to the screen without displaying the `Hello world` line.

This is the current output:

```
Hello world #This should not be here

Age
```

Troubleshooting: I have considered using `grep`, but I am trying to run this command on files that may have more complex strings in various fields than just `Age`.

Comment: `cut` doesn't extract *lines*, it extracts *columns* from every line....

Comment: `awk -F: 'NR > 1 { print $2 }' yourfile`, maybe.

Comment: Do you always want to start from the 3rd line or do you only print to print lines that contain a delimiter?

Comment: What's wrong with **grep** and what kind of complex strings are you looking for that grep cannot handle? **grep 'Age' <filename> | cut -d':' -f2**

Comment: I only want to print fields from lines that have a delimiter

Comment: @Sergiu I can't really do that because I'll be working with various files that are delimited and I don't know what exact data are in those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print only lines that contain the delimiter character use the `-s` / `--only-delimited` switch:

```sh
cut -s -d':' -f2 file.txt
```

See the [`cut` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).